# .htaccess dynamic URL rewriting in PHP Apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2, url-routing

I have a URL like

`www.example.com/program.php?course=1&program=Ajay`

now with .htaccess I am able to convert it like

`www.example.com/program/1/Ajay`

but I want to convert it like

`www.example.com/program/Ajay`

Can any one please suggest how could I do this?

Any help really appreciated.

I used this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ program\.php\?course=(.*)&program_name=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /program/%3\? [R,L]
```

Comment: Can you show your current rule?

Comment: @anubhava Its updated please check.

Comment: Why is `program_name=` in your rule> You question doesn't have any reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

The following rule should change `www.example.com/a.php?x=1&y=2&z=Ajay` to `www.example.com/target/Ajay`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /program\.php\?course=(.*)&program=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /program/%3\? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^/program/(.*)$ /program.php?program=$1 [L]
```

The `%4` refers to the value after `&z=`. If you wanted the value from `?x=` or `&y=` you would use `%2` for value in `x=` and `%3` for value in `&y=`

e.g. Change `www.example.com/a.php?x=1&y=2&z=Ajay` to `www.example.com/target/x/Ajay`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /a\.php\?x=(.*)&y=(.*)&z=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /target/%2/%4\? [R,L]
```

Comment: Adding the above to your .htaccess file in the root folder should work.

Comment: Can you edit your post and put in what is in your htaccess file?

Comment: You need to have `RewriteEngine On` in your htaccess file. Also change the `%2` to `%3`.

Comment: In your `program.php` do you have to pass a value to `course`?

Comment: You didn't add the second rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example, it may help you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^post-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ post.php?post_name=$1&post_id=$2 [L]
```